# AngularJS 1.3 and IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

So I know that AngularJS dropped support for IE8. I'd like to learn, whether this means that they won't simply test in IE8, or did they introduce some features that simply break in IE8.

Did anyone actually succeeded in setting up Angular 1.3+ application on IE8? What kind of approaches/shims are needed (modernir, es5-shims, respond.js, others?)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

After trying it on my own - no, Angular 1.3 simply won't run on IE8. It's not a matter of shims, or other libraries, or some hacks. It just won't work at all.

Comment: This is not true, and should not be marked as correct answer. Angular 1.3 might work on IE8 (using your own tests). see my answer for more details :_)

Answer (score 16):

I have Angular 1.3 working with IE8.

It requires jQuery, a couple of shims and one source code change to Angular. I'm maintaining builds of Angular with a lot of the shims baked in and instructions on what else to include here:
https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

I can't get the unit tests running properly with IE8 so can't confirm 100% compatibility, but using a broad smoke test I can confirm every feature I've ever used with Angular works fine in IE8 + 1.3

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that they've stopped testing for anything beyond 1.2.x, which enables them to "add more exciting features to Angular faster, decrease Angular's support burden, and cut [their] build time in half, while affecting only a very small proportion of users."

They're not necessarily removing the hacks from Angular that made IE8 work but there's no guarantee that changes in anything after 1.2.x won't break an application running on IE8 since they've stopped supporting it and addressing any issues that are solely related to it.

The above was what they said in a post about a year ago, so it might very well be the case that there are certain features that break today. With that said, your safest bet would be to work with 1.2.x, unless you want to use 1.3.x and test it yourself.

References:

https://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html#!http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: You're just quoting their site. I'm asking about your actual experice.

Comment: I was speaking more to the first part of your question: "I'd like to learn, whether this means that they won't simply test in IE8, or did they introduce some features that simply break in IE8."

Comment: Fair enough, but their entries are a bit vague - they don't really say if it works right now and if not - why not.

Comment: @rattkin They don't say if it works because they haven't tested, because they don't support it. It's like asking a car dealer "ok, but what happens if I drop it from an airplane with a parachute?" - they won't have an answer for you.

Comment: You do realize, that this is exactly why I'm asking you here, and not them via official channels? I want to know what are the experiences of those who tried to run Angular 1.3 on IE8.

Comment: Here's an experience i'm having; its crashing horribly expecting an object.
Yay.